# compare 2 array and find unique differences

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, performance, knockout.js

Let's say that we have two arrays

```
var firstArray = [{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":5}]
var secondArray = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]
var missingValues = [];

for(var i=0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
  for(var j=0; j < secondArray.length; j++) {
      if(firstArray[i].id === secondArray[j].id) {
         //do something if I have the same id
      } else {
        missingValues.push(secondArray[j].id); // it should have unique values
      }
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < missingValues.length; i++) {
  //compare first array and missigValues and remove the same elements
}
```

I want to have the following result. Which means that I need to compare two arrays and remove all objects that are not in the second array but I also need to keep the same order

```
firstArray = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4]
```

Is there any better way of doing this? Something more performance wise since those arrays could have a really big amount of JSON data inside.
I want to avoid multiple nesting as much as possible.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you need to do?

Comment: @dandavis: I was assuming that those simply were stand-ins for more complex objects that happened to have such properties among others.

Comment: Should your output really contain `{id: 2}` ?  If so, it looks as though all you need to do is some sort of cloning of the second array.

Comment: Are you sure that the result array you mention is correct?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but your example makes it look like you just need to replace `firstArray` with `secondArray`. If you only wanted to remove from `firstArray` whats not in `secondArray` your desired output should ***NOT*** contain `2` or `4`

Comment: is _id_ the only criterion?

Comment: Your example **still** seems to allow for returning the second array or a clone.  Is that really what you want?  Your words seem to say something different.

Comment: do you only want to keep the element if it has both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a temp primitive array to prevent the slow user-land nested looping:

```
var firstArray = [{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":5}]
var secondArray = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]

var temp=secondArray.map(function(o){return o.id;});

var common=firstArray.filter(function(a){
 return temp.indexOf(a.id)!==-1;
});

JSON.stringify(common) // [{"id":1},{"id":3}]
```

this approach assumes that *id* the the only important value by which to establish uniqueness, but it's very quick.

if *id* is always going to be a number, and you will never have a meaningful case otherwise (ex {id:1} vs {id:"1"}, you can make it even faster by using object keys to establish uniqueness:

```
var firstArray = [{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":5}]
var secondArray = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]

var temp={};
 secondArray.forEach(function(o){temp[o.id]=1; });

var common=firstArray.filter(function(a){
 return temp[a.id]; //note no nested operation at all!
});

JSON.stringify(common) // [{"id":1},{"id":3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that matches the textual description as I understand it, but not the (current) examples.  It may be incorrect:

```
var firstArray = [{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":5}]
var secondArray = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]

var foundIn = function(list) {
    var ids = list.reduce(function(ids, item) {ids[item.id] = 1; return ids;}, {});
    return function(item) {return !!ids[item.id];};
};

var result = firstArray.filter(foundIn(secondArray)); //=> [{"id":1},{"id":3}]
```

If you want to make a completely reusable function out of this, you could add

```
var onlyFoundIn = function(list1, list2) {return list1.filter(foundIn(list2));};
```

Then

```
onlyFoundIn(firstArray, secondArray); //=>  [{"id":1},{"id":3}]
```

But it's still not clear if this actually does what you want.